# Eas update: my already published React Native App gets the old version when installing it

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, eas

I have an app published on the internal test track in the Google Play Store console, and I'm using the EAS update from Expo. Every new user who installs the app and opens the app for the first time sees the version that was current at the time I built the bundle and not the latest version pushed through the EAS update. On the second open, they see the current version.

I understand the mechanism behind this, but I have some questions:

1. If I use the update API to check for a new version and force a refresh in the app, should I disable the option `expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH` in the manifest?
2. Is there a better way to refresh the app after EAS checks for a new version without using the Update API?

My current script is:

```
async () => {
    try {
        const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
        if (update.isAvailable) {
            await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
            await Updates.reloadAsync();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        crashlytics().recordError(error, `Error fetching latest Expo update`);
    } finally {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
}
```

However, in the Android manifest, I'm also using this:

```
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
```

Should I choose one to use? Is there a problem with using both?

My concern is to do a double-check on the EAS update...so one of them will be unnecessary.